# Trigger Build through push notification

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, gitlab

I'm trying to trigger a build through a http request as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository). But when I send the request like

```
curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>
```

I get this:

```
Jobs found but they aren't configured for polling
```

I can't find any option to allow this. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your **Job Configuration**, scroll down to **Build Triggers** section, and checkmark **Poll SCM**. Configure the cron schedule for something infrequent, like once a month.